# Cech-complete separable groups

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

It is well known that a Baire measurable homomorphism between Polish groups is continuous.

> Is the same true if we replace Polish groups by [Cech-complete](http://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Cech-complete_space), separable groups?

It is not true without the separability assumption. On the other hand, second countable Cech-complete spaces are metrisable, so this is why I arrived at separability.

Comment: What about trying $(S^1)^\kappa$ for uncountable $\kappa$?